# How do find out the web path of a screen?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-navigation, expo

I'm looking to have a [expo's push notification](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/#message-format) direct the user to a certain screen on my app:

> // Web-specific fields
>
> /**    * The web path that will be opened/focused after the user
>   clicks the    * notification.    * Defaults to "/" (root)    */
>   webPath?: string,

If my screen architecture looks something like the following:

```js
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
            Home: {
                screen: createStackNavigator({
                    Home: {
                        screen: HomeScreen,
                    },
                    Map: {
                        screen: MapScreen,
                    },
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

what is the exact `webPath` of the `MapScreen`?